# How to change color of my font using forEach()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the font color on my buttons for my calculator, and I want to use the forEach method (or even a loop) to make all the text the color blue. I don't want every color blue, just the numbers 0-9 and the decimal.

I also want to know how to get the numbers to display on my black input box so it looks like an actual calculator, and how to save the numbers into a DOM element.

```js
//3.
//Changing colors of opertion colors 

//Multiply Color
const colorMultiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
colorMultiply.style.backgroundColor = "green" //Makes Color Green

//Divide Color
const colorDivide = document.getElementById('divide')
colorDivide.style.backgroundColor = "red"//Makes Color Red

//subtract color
const colorSubtract = document.getElementById('subtract')
colorSubtract.style.backgroundColor="blue"//Makes Color Blue

//add color
const colorAdd = document.getElementById('add')
colorAdd.style.backgroundColor="yellow"//Makes Color Yellow


//change font of numbers to blue (I did it like this incase anyone wants to color of a single number)
//Makes it easier for you to change a colour of one button
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"

//Changing color of the clear button
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
clear.style.color="white"
clear.style.backgroundColor="black"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then we want to insert `memoryStoreButton` before the `clear` button:
var memoryStoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryStoreButton.innerHTML = "MS";
clear.before(memoryStoreButton); //puts button before clear

// Then we want the `memoryClearButton` before `memoryStoreButton`
var memoryClearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryClearButton.innerHTML = "MC";
memoryStoreButton.before(memoryClearButton);//puts button before clear

// and finally, the `memoryRestoreButton` before `memoryClearButton`
var memoryRestoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryRestoreButton.innerHTML = "MR";
memoryClearButton.before(memoryRestoreButton);//puts button before clear

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//What buttons are pressed
var expression = [];

document.querySelector(".buttons8").onclick = function(e){
  if(e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    if(e.target.innerHTML !== "=") {
      expression.push(e.target.innerHTML);
    } else {
      console.log( eval(expression.join("")) );
      expression = [];
    }
  }
}
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;

}

.calculator8{
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.screen8{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 7rem;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background: rgb(41,41,56);
 color: white;
 border:none;
}

.buttons8{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button{
 flex:0 0 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.25rem 0;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

.btn-kground: rgb(224,224,224);
}

.btn8{
 font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<title> Calculator 8 </title>
 <script src="fp.js" defer></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fp.css">



</head>

<body>
 <section class="calculator8">
    <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>


  </div>



 </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so set the `color`?

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: i've tried what is show, and the forEach that I do changes colors of all the buttons, and I don't know how to select the only the few.

Comment: (0) Why would you give a class like "btn-gray" which sounds like a colour? (1) Why wouldn't you give all the digits the same class, ready for targetting with CSS selectors?

Comment: the button colors are grey

Comment: @EvanMunroe - well then, why not `btn-grey-with-white-text-probably`? The point was, it's not a good idea to make classes with names like that. Does the word probably help you at all? You've said you'd like to change the text color, or at least make it easy. Would someone *never* change the background also? If you have a`btn-operator` and a `btn-number` class, you can assign it where appropriate. You can assign the same background-color to both classes in css, while retaining the ability to to do `var numBtnArr = Array.from(getElementsByClassName('btn-number'));` - `numBtnArr.forEach` awaits!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was getting at - using a class that differentiates the digits and the period from the operator buttons. It's just a simple matter of making an array from all the elements that have the class, then steping through this list and doing whatever's necessary.

```js
"use strict";

var btnText = ['MC', 'MR', 'MS', 'M+', 'M-', '<-', 'CE', 'C', '±', '√', '7', '8', '9', '/', '%',
  '4', '5', '6', '*', '1/x', '1', '2', '3', '-', '=', '0', '.', '+'
];

var digsAndPeriod = "01234567890.";

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt) {
  let cellArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td'));
  cellArr.forEach((cell, idx, arr) => {
    let btn = document.createElement('button');
    var curText = btnText[idx];
    btn.textContent = curText;
    if (digsAndPeriod.indexOf(curText) != -1)
      btn.classList.add('btn-num');
    cell.appendChild(btn);
  });


  document.getElementById('goBtn').addEventListener('click', onGoBtnClicked, false);
}

function onGoBtnClicked(evt) {
  let numBtns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.btn-num'));
  numBtns.forEach(btn => btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red');
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 34px;
  height: 27px;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-num {
  background-color: #f2f6fa;
  color: #1e395b;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-num:hover {
  background-color: #ffcf6a;
}

th {
  border: solid 1px black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th colspan='5'>0123456789</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td rowspan='2'></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id='goBtn'>GO! (Re-colour)</button>
```